# Strange FTP error gets resolved after deleting and adding back user account

Tags: c#, windows-7

So I have a C# Windows Application within which I have an FTP method that works for sure.

Strangely the application fails at the FTP part for a particular user account(with Admin privileges) and it does not happen always. Pretty random. Even stranger part is when we delete that account and recreate it with Admin privileges, it works fine again.

PS- The FTP server and this box are all on the same network, so the FTP server is pingable always.

Any ideas why it fails randomly for the FTP?

Comment: Nothing on a computer is truly random. I think we probably need more info here ...

Comment: I just ran the application for both the user accounts and did not face the FTP error. It ran just fine.

Comment: What is the error code/message (on client side and on server side)? Which account are you recreating? The one on the PC where the client app runs?

Comment: In the code I have a try catch block around the FTP method that pops out a message box. The error is always on the client trying to FTP data from a server. We have two user accounts both having admin privileges and these accounts sit on the client box. 

Essentially I am reusing the FTP method from our own library, and it fails at that step. Since this morning its been fine. No errors.

Comment: Then I would suggest that it is a problem with your FTP library can you get a stacktrace if you do a ToString() on the exception this will give you more information. Post that here when you find this out.

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required".
That is the exact error.Our firewall is turned off though. So I am not really clear on what the exact issue is. The FTP method passes the username and password as arguments as well.